# Chrome request blocking doesnt work with extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to block all the requests which contain some sort of ads data, but some of them do not work for some reason..For example I want to block https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id url so I added the code like so:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function() {
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {
        urls: ["*://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/*"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

But for some reason it is not blocked at all as seen in the images below. If I add an url to block for https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js (added like `"*://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js"`) it will block just fine.. **What could be the problem?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I recommend checking out [uBlock Origin's github page](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock), which also blocks requests related to ads, and is pretty efficient.

Comment: Might be a bug in the browser. Things you can try: 1) examine `chrome://net-internals/`, 2) Chrome Canary.

Comment: @PredatorIWD I am using uBlock but their source code is just too complicated for me. I am just wondering why this url is not being blocked and the others are